# VueJs Call plugin from .js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, toast

I need you to get deeper understanding of how I can work with vueJS.

**My app**

I have a `Login.vue` which is calling a function `logUser() from UserActions.js` that is calling my `AxiosFacade.js' function postRequest()`

I use a plugin to display Toaster information with `createApp(App).use(Toaster).mount('#app')` and call my toaster with `` this.$toast.show(`Default Toast Message`); ``

**What I want to do**

I would like to call my function `this.$toast.show` from the catch parts of my axios' calls in `AxiosFacade.js`

Something like :

```
return axios.post(`${serv}/${ressource}`,
    {
        data: params,
    },
    {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}})
    .then((response) => response = response.data)
    .catch((err) => {
        this.$toast.error(err.response.data.message);
        throw err.response.data.message
    })
```

But I don't really understand how can I make links from .js and .vue files

PS : Next step would be to have my own Toaster.vue component and showing/hiding it from my AxiosFacade.js too, if you have tips for this too :)

Thanks !

Comment: `this` wont work in custom js files because its not a vue reference

Comment: Yeah, I saw this from the ```undefined``` I see in my console, but I don't know how I could access to my function

Comment: you need to import vue from main.js file

Comment: I'm sorry but, I might need a little bit more informations to get the all process to follow.
I ```import Vue from 'vue'``` in main.js, but how can I call my function in the other file ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the catch part of your axios function

```
return axios.post(`${serv}/${ressource}`,
{
    data: params,
},
{headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}})
.then((response) => response = response.data)
```

and catch it where you want to show the toast. Login.vue:

```
function logUser () {
  return postRequest()
    .then(responseData => {
      //do your stuff
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.$toast.error(err.response.data.message)
      throw err.response.data.message
    })
}
```

### Update:

The solutions is actual pretty easy. You just need add your method where `this` needs to be the vue instance to your component.

See following example:

accessVueInstance.js:

```js
export function compare(vueInstance) {
  return this === vueInstance
}
```

MyComponent.vue:

import the function

`import { compare } from "./accessVueInstance"`

add the function to your component:

if you use class components:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  compare = compare

  created() {
    console.log(this.compare(this)) //will log true
  }
  //your stuff
}
```

else:

```js
methods: {
  compare
},
created() {
  console.log(this.compare(this)) //will log true
}
```

[vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#methods)

> Vue automatically binds the this value for methods so that it always
> refers to the component instance.

See it in action [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-firefly-9166x?file=/src/App.vue:315-344)

Comment: That's my actual solution

But the behaviour is always the same "if error then display error returned by the backend"
I wanted to refactor my code to put this repetitive code in the Axios facade and clean my code

Comment: you could try to make AxiosFacade.js  a [vue plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) or you need to pass the vue instance into *AxiosFacade.js*. If you show me what *AxiosFacade.js* looks like I can help you with that.

Comment: I've dropped AxiosFacade.js and UserAction.js as an answer :)
Thx for your help